# Firefox Input Label and jquery 1.9

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, input, label

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way of detecting firefox without the use of .browser (since jquery 1.9 has it as deprecated)

Essentially I have this HTML:

```
<label class="uploadButton" for="test">Test</label>
<input type="file" name="test"/>
```

This works fine for IE and chrome but does nothing in Firefox. Pre 1.9 I had this:

```
if ($.browser.mozilla) {
    $('.uploadButton').click(function () {
        $(this).siblings("input").click();
    });
}
```

Which worked without issues.

What would be the best way of making this work now that the .browser property is gone?

(I looked under features and found no feature that would detect something like this as well..)

Comment: It lloks like a dup of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9638247/is-jquery-browser-deprecated)

Comment: I can't use .support because this is not a supported "feature"

Comment: Can you use [migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/)?

Comment: Migrate is not an option at this point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found

```
ua = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()
```

as part of an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372831/why-is-browser-deprecated-and-what-is-a-better-alternative).